# Register module runtime vs transpile time

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I just want to confirm my understanding of Vuex store module registration.

My understanding is that

```
const store = {
  modules: {
    mod1,
    mod2,
    mod3,
    ...
  }
}

export default store
```

registers the module during transpile time, when `.vue` and other webpack stuff is happening, whereas

```
store.registerModule('mod1', mod1)
store.registerModule('mod2', mod2)
store.registerModule('mod3', mod3)
```

happens at runtime when the code actually gets to the client, making the frontend ever so slightly slower.

Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: The official docs for `registerModule()` gives plugin integration as an 
 example usage, but plugins are part of the compile - so not really 'runtime' in that scenario.

Comment: This blog [Vue.js App Performance Optimization: part 3— Lazy loading Vuex modules](https://itnext.io/vue-js-app-performance-optimization-part-3-lazy-loading-vuex-modules-ed67cf555976) gives another example usage for bundling modules in different webpack chunks for lazy loading, so again is compile time not runtime - in the sense that the compiler already knows about the module, even if it is added to the store during a runtime execution path.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes. 
Register a module **before** the store has been created

```
 const store = {
      modules: {
        mod1,
        mod2,
        mod3,
        ...
      }
    }

    export default store
```

I recommend to you read the [official documentation for more information](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html):

> *Dynamic Module Registration*
>
> You can register a module **after** the store has been created with the `store.registerModule` method.